# How far can our modern day tech achieve in absence of gold element?

Tags: technological-development, classical-elements

Suppose man never discover gold could we still be able to have internet or perhaps even achieve nuclear fusion to get gold? I realized most of the sensitive piece of equipment had traces of gold in it, and thus the element must played an important role in our understanding of experimental physics of today other then its worth.

Comment: This question would probably receive better answers on a [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) or [engineering.SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/). E.g.: *What role is gold playing in modern day electronics and could similar effects be achieved without it?*

Comment: The market for ultra-priced hifi-cables would not exist. Nothing else would change.

Comment: "I realized most of the sensitive piece of equipment had traces of gold in it, and **thus the element must played an important role in our understanding of experimental physics of today other than its worth.**" - your premise is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't change anything.

Gold is only used because it happens to have a better resistance to corrosion and conductiveness than many other metals.

If gold wasn't available, another metal would be found, although things might corrode a big quicker.  But, this isn't really a huge issue as most consumer electronics reach the end of their useful life before corrosion sets in.

[Wikipedia - gold as an electronical connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold#Electronics_connectors)